# How to package all .dll files and .exe into one file in C#, just like Java does about Jar

Tags: c#

When developing a WinForm application, we have to create an installation package for this project and send it to our customer. The customer has to install the application and run it.
Otherwise we can send the Bin folder to customer, which contains .exe and .dll

Is there any way to package all the files into one file and the customer can just run it by double click the file? Just like Jave does about Jar.

I find a solution in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15044/The-NAR-loader-single-file-NET-deployment). But this is old, in 2006. I am not sure it can use with today's framwork version. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Possibly you want ILMerge? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1829531/56778

Comment: @John Saunders The version of VS is vs2010, and it is a winfrom application.

Comment: @JimMischel Will ILMerge merge all files including .dll, .txt, .config or will it just merge all .dll files into one file?

Comment: I don't know if it will merge .txt, .config, etc. I know that it will merge assemblies. If you need to merge other types of files and ILMerge won't handle it, you could create a resource assembly. The linked question has a link to ILMerge. Download it and see if it'll do what you need.

Comment: You may want to try describing the details of the functionality you want. Not all .NET people are familiar with exactly what a .jar file is.

Comment: Add your extra files as embedded resources in the exe file. Then override the assemblyresolve event to handle dlls (e.g http://stackoverflow.com/a/9180843/157224).  For the other files you need to change File.Open into ResourceStream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Windows Installer Package.

The WIX Toolset is a Visual Studio extension you can install, which allows you to create an installation package.

http://wixtoolset.org/

Previous versions of Visual Studio supported an "Installer" project type, but this was discontinued. Hence the need for a third-party extension.

Comment: I think OP doesn't want an installer, he want's a single executable that would run as is