# Resource assembly binding from specific folder

Tags: c#

Scenario: Foreign application host (.exe) loads my assembly (some kind of a addin) which in turn needs to load the resource assemblies.

For now this works only when i copy the resource assemblies into the main folder of the host application. BUT i wanna leave them in my specific installation folder. How to achieve this?

Normally when using my application i place the resource assemblies in app.exe\langcode folder.

Regards

Comment: Do you have a first called method (or static ctor) that won't cause the resources to be searched? In that case add your own `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` (in `CurrentDomain`, I suppose) to manually load them from the _right_ folder (which you obtain from assembly location of `GetExecutingAssembly()`)

Comment: Cannot use `this.assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file_name);`?

Comment: The runtime uses standard .NET mechanism to load resource assemblies. Which looks for a folder named <iso 2 code laguage specifier>. In my scenario some other application loads may dll which needs to locate may resources! Is know clearer?

Comment: is the foreingen app configurable or it does require all .dll in on specific folder?

Comment: The foreign app has an app.config! The only solution may be to write a reference to the satelite assemblies into it?!? You mean that?

Answer (score 0):

In configuration files you can use the runtime section to configure this.  Otherwise you need to use AppDomain.AssemblyResolve which is most likely the case in your scenario.

```
<runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="[DLL Name]" publicKeyToken="[Token]"/>
              <codeBase version="[Version/Range]" href="langcode/[DLL Name].dll"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

[Working with AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180638/working-with-appdomain-assemblyresolve-event)

Comment: This only works for app.config? My dll does not look into the app.config as it seams. The app.exe does.