# How to use DLL from the C drive while running the exe from the debug folder?

Tags: vb.net

I have several DLL files in C:\RLM85LTD\

e.g.
C:\RLM85LTD\Interop.MSXML2.dll

My app from the Debug folder is in a folder on my desktop called my apps. when I opened the app from my apps folder it does not work unless the relevant DLL's are in my apps folder.

How can I get the app to work with the DLL in C:\RLM85LTD.

Comment: The argument to LoadFrom() is nonsensical.  You can kinda see it by noticing that you didn't use the *file* variable and it is definitely not a document.

Comment: Have you found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180638/working-with-appdomain-assemblyresolve-event) SO question about using AssemblyResolve in your searching?  Might be of help.

Comment: @SeanSkelly I had a look at what you suggested, but I am not sure how to fully convert and use in vb.net. mainly the raised events